# How do I test back() method in laravel

Tags: laravel, testing

I want to test back() function in laravel but I am not sure how to do that .

For e.g

```
 public function destroy($id)
{
    $query = Query::findorfail($id);
    $query->delete();

    return back()->with('success','Query deleted successfully');
}
```

In the above method the url is redirected back . But Can I create a test so that I can assert back()

Comment: Start with the docs: [Http Tests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/http-tests)

Answer (score 2):

I have checked the [TestResponse class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestResponse.php). A function like assertRedirectBack is not yet provided.

I think assertRedirect is gonna work:

```
$response = $this->delete(...);


$response->assertRedirect($uri);
```

The previous url could be stored in session. I am not sure about that. So please try this:

```
$response->assertRedirect(session()->previousUrl());
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `TestCase`'s [from](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php#L305) (from `MakesHttpRequests` trait)

```
$response = $this
  ->from('{route}') // without this would redirect to '/'
  ->delete('/asset/{id}');

$response->assertRedirect('{route}');
```

Answer (score -3):

Try with `return redirect()->back();`